# Getting equation from differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have:

$\dfrac {dx} {dt}$=$-x+y$

$\dfrac {dy}{dt}$=$-x-y$

and I am trying to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ given that $x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$

I know to do this I need to decouple the equations so that I only have to deal with one variable but the decoupling is what I am having trouble with

Do I set them equal to each other and then just move like terms to separate sides getting two different equations and then integrate?

Comment: You can write the as a matrix equation $x' = Ax$, find the eigenvalues, vectors and then sub in the ICs. You can also go backward to original DEQ and solve that too. You should get $x(t) = e^{-t} \sin t, y(t) = e^{-t} \cos t$.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate both w.r.t. t again, we end up with
$$
d^2x/dt^2 = -dx/dt+dy/dt
$$
$$
d^2y/dt^2 = -dx/dt-dy/dt
$$

Then add both of them. Remember that $y=dx/dt + x$

We get
$$
d^2(x+y)/dt^2 = -2dx/dt
$$
Substitute the value of $y = dx/dt +x $
You get,
$$
d^3x/dt^3 + 2d^2x/dt^2 + 2dx/dt = 0
$$

Mathematica(or setting $dx/dt = u$) will give the answer as
$$
x(t) = 1/2 exp(-t) ((c_2-c_1) sin(t)-(c_1+c_2) cos(t))+c_3
$$

Comment: I am looking for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ separately

Comment: sorry, I have edited. Please check.

Comment: I think that there is probably a way to decouple these equations into separate equations for $x$ and $y$ without using any derivatives of order higher than $2$, since it is a two-dimensional system to begin with.  I'll try to get to it . . . in a while.

Comment: @RobertLewis Cher ami, but look, the ultimate differential equation looks like a third order one, when in actuality, by the substitution of ($dx/dt = u$) should make it a second order one. It is infact a well known form of a second order d.e, the damped oscillator!

Comment: @Anurag Pallaprolu, achiy, *et al*:  Whoops, I fear I didn't carefully read your equation much past the $\frac{d^3x}{dt^3}$ term!  But I still suspect there is a line of attack involving only derivatives or order two or less.  Also, the presence of *three* arbitrary constants in your Mathematica solution is puzzling.  Shalom.

Comment: @Robertlewis ah Mon dieu. I was using Mathematica to solve the third order one, it spat out three constants. My bad. But yes, I was just trying to answer the OPs question of reducing two equations to one.the rest of the answers have completely missed this point, Mon ami!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are seeking for a possiblity to *separate* the equations as common with some of the systems, by shifting the system parallel to the existing $x$ and $y$ coordinates. In simple words you want to find a way by addition or subtraction or multiplication or division. A fair answer is that this is not possible with this system, you can not just scale it. You need to *rotate* it.

You would see this from the solution of the equation with

$$x(t) = e^{-t} \sin t$$
$$y(t) = e^{-t} \cos t$$

you see there the trigonometric term and $\sin$ and $\cos$ depicting that $y$ and $x$ are shifted at a rotation of $\pi/2$ against each other.

But a priori you dont have of course the solution and the only way to know about the demand for a rotation is due to the fact that you feel by yourself intuitively the system has a resistence and you can not just stretch it. The positive and negative signs just make it impossible to manage a separation by only scaling - following your words.

There is no other way to solve the system by separation except via transformation in the eigenspace accepting a rotation.

You will see a way to caculation of the eigenvalues and solution of the system [here>>>](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/sysode/sode0101.pdf)

It wont make sense to copy/paste all.

The solution path for such equations via transformation is standard straight forward and cares about all stretching/scaling and rotation required. You can find it also in other books/literature.

Hope this helps out of all confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you change your variables from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ according to the rule
$$\begin{cases}x=a u+bv \\y=cu+dv \end{cases}. $$
This can be written in a matrix form $\mathbf x=P \mathbf u$ where $P=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$.

The ODE transforms accordingly, from
$$\frac{ \mathrm d \mathbf x}{\mathrm d t}=A \mathbf x $$ to
$$P\frac{ \mathrm d \mathbf u}{\mathrm d t}=AP \mathbf u,   $$ or
$$\frac{ \mathrm d \mathbf u}{\mathrm d t}=P^{-1}AP \mathbf u.  $$
If you choose the "right" matrix $P$ the equations for $u,v$ become uncoupled and you can solve them. Then it takes a simple multiplication by $P^{-1}$ to get back to $x,y$.

Comment: isnt this practically identical to solving the system through transformation into eigenspace via evalues and evectors?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi It is. But I wasn't sure that OP was familiar with the  method, so I elaborated.